# Start a process on the server instead of client

Tags: c#, asp.net, process, client-server, code-behind

I have a button in an ASP.NET form that when you press it, at the code-behind it will run a Process.Start() command.
My PC is acting as a server, and when I press the button from a client, it will try to run that command on the client's PC. How can I make that command run on the server PC?

ASP Control:

```
<asp:Button ID="ButtonRun" runat="server" Font-Size="XX-Large" Text="Run"
onclick="ButtonRun_Click" />
```

Code-behind Function:

```
protected void ButtonRun_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Process.Start(MapPath(botPath));
    }
```

Of course, this is all password protected. IE, you can't call the function unless you authenticate first.

Comment: How did you able to do that from a browser ?????

Comment: Well the above code would never start a process on client. It will start the process on server. Not really sure how you are testing it.

Comment: @Habib, please see comment on the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

[Process.Start](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53ezey2s%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) always starts the process on the machine where the function is invoked, so in your case the process is always started on the server.  When that fails, ASP.Net generates an error page, which is what you see in the browser.  So why does it sometimes succeed and sometimes fail?  There's not enough context here to say, but I would guess that `botPath` has different values in the two cases.  You can try hard-coding it to validate that hypothesis.

A tool like [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) will show you the attempts to start a new process, in case you have doubt that they are all being started on the server.  It will also record the path to the executable, which may be helpful for trouble-shooting.

Comment: Won't the fact that the error page states the executable isn't a valid OS application, means that it doesn't actually start it on the server?

Comment: It's an error so the process doesn't start anywhere.  It's attempting to start it on the server but there's a problem with the executable file.

Comment: Ok, keeping that in mind, how can it be possible that when I debug it, everything is fine. When I browse the website using the server PC, everything is fine. When I browse the website using a client, it does nothing (a client PC) or produces an error (a client mobile)

Comment: I guess because different values of `botPath` are used in those cases.  It would be helpful if there was enough code in the question to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thought about it, and no.
I'm currently at work, when I'll get back I hope I'll remember to update with the full code (though not much of it anyway)

Answer (score 0):

Anything written on the server side will be executed on the server. For the code you have given above, the Process will start on the server by default.

Comment: I tried executing it on my phone with remote debugging on, this is what happened: http://i57.tinypic.com/23rwdup.jpg
This happens with the ProcessStartInfo property "UseShellExecute" set to false. With it set to true, nothing happens.